# How can I export image in Adobe Illustrator to a specific resolution?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I need 120x120 pixel image, but Illustrator is asking for ppi.

Strange I can not set less than 72 pixel / inch, or if I set the rendered image will have 72.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand that resolution and dimensions are generally two different things?

Comment: I found that Xcode 6.0 supports now vector images, so my whole problem could  have an other approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149785/xcode-6-allows-vector-image-assets-any-idea-how-to-use-them

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to export at a given resolution, instead of exporting as PNG, choose File > Save for Web. On the right side you will be given the option to specify your PNG file dimensions in pixels, allowing you to export below 72ppi without changing your Illustrator canvas/image size.

Comment: Depending on the Illustrator version you may want to search for 
`File > Export > Save for Web`

Answer (score 0):

Resolution determines how many Pixels Per Inch (ppi) an image has.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density

So an image that is 120 pixels by 120 pixels could be any size really, because you could make a 72ppi or 300ppi, or any other number.

Your best bet to achieve a 120px by 120px image would be to create a blank image of that size in Photoshop (or another image-editing program), and import your Illustrator file into the image, and then save it as your desired file format.

Alternately, you can change your units of measure in Illustrator to pixels instead of inches, and create the image at 120px by 120px there. Then you would use the export box you've posted a screenshot of.

Basic rule of them for most instances is:
For Internet or on-screen applications, export at 72ppi using RGB color.
For Print applications, export at 300ppi using CMYK color.

Comment: change your units of measure in Illustrator to pixels instead of inches does not work, after changing it still `ppi` I have to set at export